# Anychart : How to add animation in Pie or funnel chart of AnyChart7.1

Tags: javascript, animation, charts, pie-chart, anychart

I am using latest version of anychart. They provide the animation features using

```
chart.animation(true)
```

This feature working fine for line chart and other charts like column but this does not work with many charts. So how can i add the animation for pie and funnel charts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animation issue is fixed in [release 7.12.0](http://www.anychart.com/products/anychart/history/?version=7.12.0) 
Please, take a look at

[Pie Chart](http://jsfiddle.net/jqqgf5r1/8/) sample

```
    chart.animation(true, 800);
```

[Funnel Chart](http://jsfiddle.net/one4Lj02/) sample

```
    chart.animation(true, 800);
```

[Pyramid Chart](http://jsfiddle.net/one4Lj02/1/) sample

```
    chart.animation(true, 800);
```

Comment: Is there anyway to animate each individual slice of the pie as it pops out?

Answer (score 0):

Right now, because of the bug in AnyChart, there is no way to turn animation for Pie and Funnel charts.
We will fix it as soon as possible.