# Anychart chart.animation breaks pie3d chart type

Tags: javascript, anychart

I'm running 7.12.0.1229, where according to [Anychart : How to add animation in Pie or funnel chart of AnyChart7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40257869/anychart-how-to-add-animation-in-pie-or-funnel-chart-of-anychart7-1) several animation issues were fixed.

When trying to use a chart type of `pie3d` in combination with  `chart.animation(true, 800);`, `chart.animation(true);` or `chart.animation({enabled: true, duration: duration})` the chart won't render.

#### Working example http://jsfiddle.net/RainerAtSpirit/c2wye9m9/3/

```
anychart.onDocumentReady(function() {
    //dataset
    var data = anychart.data.set([
        ["$0-$50,000", 68],
        ["$50,000-$100,000", 13],
        ["$100,000-$150,000", 6],
        ["$150,000-$250,000", 6],
        ["$250,000 - plus", 7]
    ])

    var chart = anychart.pie3d(data);

    //adjust legend
    var legend = chart.legend();
    legend.enabled(true);
    legend.position("left");
    legend.align("center");
    legend.itemsLayout("vertical");

    //create title
    var title = chart.title();
    title.text("Pop Out");
    title.enabled(true);

    //inner radius makes this a doughnut chart instead of pie
    chart.innerRadius("30%");

    //define the container
    chart.container("container");

    // chart.animiation breaks pie3d chart type
    // chart.animation(true, 800);

    //set delay to recall draw ch art to
    chart.draw();
});
```

#### Broken example http://jsfiddle.net/RainerAtSpirit/c2wye9m9/2/

```
anychart.onDocumentReady(function() {
    //dataset
    var data = anychart.data.set([
        ["$0-$50,000", 68],
        ["$50,000-$100,000", 13],
        ["$100,000-$150,000", 6],
        ["$150,000-$250,000", 6],
        ["$250,000 - plus", 7]
    ])

    var chart = anychart.pie3d(data);

    //adjust legend
    var legend = chart.legend();
    legend.enabled(true);
    legend.position("left");
    legend.align("center");
    legend.itemsLayout("vertical");

    //create title
    var title = chart.title();
    title.text("Pop Out");
    title.enabled(true);

    //inner radius makes this a doughnut chart instead of pie
    chart.innerRadius("30%");

    //define the container
    chart.container("container");

    // chart.animiation breaks pie3d chart type
    chart.animation(true, 800);

    //set delay to recall draw ch art to
    chart.draw();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it doesn't look nice, thank you for the report! We transfered this case to our bug tracking system, so we will dig deep into it and get back to you as soon as possible. As for animation feature in common, 3d charts support animation:

```
chart = anychart.bar3d([2, 8, 3, 4, 9]);
chart.animation({enabled: true, duration: 3000});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/35gnevfc/)

But in case of 3d pie it doesn't work, we'll investigate it shortly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that animation is not yet supported for 3D charts. So either make the chart a 2d pie chart with animation or a 3D chart without.